# Identify electronics connector from pinout

Tags: connections, electronics

Is it possible to identify an electronics connector with the pinout diagram?

For instance, this diagram shows an 18+2 pin configuration along with a key slot of some type at the top.  The diagram happens to have come from a recent model Nissan Pathfinder audio visual service manual, and is the connector responsible for connecting the amplifier to the speakers in the vehicle.

[image: pinout diagram]

Comment: What is the model year of the Nissan Pathfinder? Also do you happen to know amplifier OEM.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena To my knowledge, all 2013+ models with the navigation option use the same head unit.  Not the Bose option.  There was a refresh in the 2016 model year though, so 2016-2019 would be a safe range.  And while I'm curious about _this_ particular connector, I'm also interested in the broader question of how I would go about identifying the connector without having to open up the vehicle.

Answer (score -1):

The pin out will be dependant on the equipment specified on the vehicle - some models have different levels of equipment due to marketing price points and the differences between models.

The manufacturer may be identifiable by markings  on the connector itself. Worth looking at the connector in detail, sometimes the text / logo etc is small.